# Project Euler: #8

Tags: java

When trying to answer this problem:

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the
>   greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> Find the thirteen
>   adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest
>   product. What is the value of this product?

I get 2091059712 however Euler says the answer is incorrect is there anything I may be doing incorrectly?

```
public class LargestProductThirteen{
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    final String num = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    long greatestProduct = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length() - 12; i++) {
        long sum = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i))* 
            Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+1))* 
            Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+2))* 
            Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+3))* 
            Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+4))* 
            Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+5))* 
            Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+6))* 
            Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+7))* 
            Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+8))* 
            Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+9))* 
            Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+10))* 
            Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+11))* 
            Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+12));
        if (sum > greatestProduct)
            greatestProduct = sum;
    }
    System.out.println(greatestProduct);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you at least quote the task here, please?

Comment: Project Euler specifically stated not to post the answers on public forums

Comment: I did not see anyone talk about this. If we are to find the product of the consecutive 13 digits and one of the digit is a 0, then we can skip past as the product will be 0. In essence, you can actually skip past the digits until you find a non zero value. None of the algorithms below talks about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are performing integer arithmetic when you are multiplying all those characters' numeric values together.  With high digits, and 13 of them, it is likely that such a product would overflow an `int`, whose max value is about 2 billion (10 digits).

The [`Character.getNumericValue` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-char-) returns an `int`.  Cast the first return value as a `long` to force `long` math.

```
long sum = (long) Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i))* 
   Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+1))* 
   ...
```

Incidentally, even though you have `greatestProduct` already, for some reason you defined this variable as `sum`.  Just for semantics' sake, I would name it `product`.

Answer (score 3):

You are currently doing integer multiplication (e.g. multiplication of int(s)). Given your existing code - the easiest solution that I see is to change your sum calculation,

```
// This is a product, not a sum.
long sum = Long.valueOf(num.charAt(i))
        * Long.valueOf(num.charAt(i + 1))
        * Long.valueOf(num.charAt(i + 2))
        * Long.valueOf(num.charAt(i + 3))
        * Long.valueOf(num.charAt(i + 4))
        * Long.valueOf(num.charAt(i + 5))
        * Long.valueOf(num.charAt(i + 6))
        * Long.valueOf(num.charAt(i + 7))
        * Long.valueOf(num.charAt(i + 8))
        * Long.valueOf(num.charAt(i + 9))
        * Long.valueOf(num.charAt(i + 10))
        * Long.valueOf(num.charAt(i + 11))
        * Long.valueOf(num.charAt(i + 12));
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a good puzzle.

Your code is failing because you are using Character.getNumericValue. You could use BigDecimal instead.

Hints
* Don't think that the whole number is a long String.
* You are looking for the max number, not the result.
* Adjacent goes in all directions.
* Don't try to use longs (or any other number containers). Regardless of the result, 9*9*7 is greater than 7*7*7. You don't have to multiply them to know that, so build a structure that finds the greatest between the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Alexandre Santos comments, treat each 13 digit number as a string of 13 chars, you can sort the chars within the string, so 98031 becomes 01389, order of operands doesn't matter with multiplication (9*8*3 = 3*8*9). Now the problem is just finding the largest string ( compare strings with <). You only have to do the multiplication once, after you have found the largest string (by sort order not size.

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation (using `for` instead of 13 similar things):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String x = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    int numberOfDigits = 13;
    int dif = x.length() - numberOfDigits;
    long max = 0;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i <= dif ; i++ ) {
        long p = 1;
        int sup = i + numberOfDigits;       
        for ( int j = i ; j < sup ; j++ ) {
            p*=Character.getNumericValue(x.charAt(j));
        }
        if ( p > max ) {
            max = p; 
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);
}
```

---

It can be **improved** using the following observation:

> 0 * ? = 0

- simple example:

  ```
  if ( x.charAt(i) == '0' ) {
      continue;
  }
  ```