# Euler Challenge 8

Tags: java

I have been working on this for a while, and I can't quite figure out why my code is printing 2091059712, which is apparently incorrect. For those who don't know, [the challenge](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) is to find the 13 adjacent digits in that long string that multiply to equal the highest number product.

```
package Project_Euler;

public class problem8 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //These 2 variables are chosen by the user. For the purpose of Euler Challenge, I have these values set as they are.
        int numToTest = 13;
        String num = "731671765313306249192251196744265747423553491949349698352031277450632623957831801698480186947885184385861560789112949" +
            "49545950173795833195285320880551112540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557668966489504452445231617318564030987111" +
            "21722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121" +
            "88399879790879227492190169972088809377665727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243525849077116705560136048395864467" +
            "06324415722155397536978179778461740649551492908625693219784686224828397224137565705605749026140797296865241453510047482166" +
            "37048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456" +
            "82848912883142607690042242190226710556263211111093705442175069416589604080719840385096245544436298123098787992724428490918" +
            "88458015616609791913387549920052406368991256071760605886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725716362695618826704282" +
            "52483600823257530420752963450";

        //setting basic variables
        int test = numToTest - 1;
        int length = num.length();
        int[] array = new int[length];
        int result = 0;
        int[] testing = new int[numToTest];
        int product = 1;

        //Setting the array to have values equal to the corresponding values in the number above.
        for(int n = 0; n <= length - 1; n++){
            //The minus 48 is because the code adds 48 to the value for some reason
            array[n] = Integer.valueOf(num.charAt(n) - 48);
        }

        //Multiplies 13 digits together and tests which set comes out with the highest product
        for(int n = 0; n < length; n++){

            //assures that it only checks when there are enough digits to multiply together
            if(n + test < length){
                product = 1;

                //goes through the digits, multiplying them by the next one.
                for(int check = 0; check <= test; check++){
                        product *= array[n + check];
                        testing[check] = array[n + check];
                }
                //finds the greatest product
                if(product > result){
                    result = product;
                }
            }
        }
        //Prints the greatest product
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

I have checked that the numbers involved are correct, and same with each code statement.

Comment: Integer overflow. Use a `long`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project Euler: #8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941868/project-euler-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `int`s result and product are too big to fit into a 32-bit integer, choose to use `long` or `BigInteger` (64-bits and more respectively.)

You are performing integer arithmetic where you multiply 13 together; such a product would cause overflow to int, where the max value is about 2 billion

Comment: But the integer result and product are used in the program, which results in an overflow

Comment: Because I am creating an array of single digits, that is not needed. However, changing the solution variable to a long did fix the problem.

Comment: When you multiplied the single digits with each other, you exceeded the int value on the vars result and product

Comment: Crud I completely forgot about that feature. Woops.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static long productSeries() {
        final String num = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";



    long greatestProduct = 0;
    int adjacentDigit = 13;

    for (int i = 0; i < num.length() - adjacentDigit; i++) {
        long sum = 1;

        for (int j = 1; j <= adjacentDigit; j++) {
            sum *= (long) Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i + j));
        }

        if (sum > greatestProduct) {
            greatestProduct = sum;
        }
    }
    return greatestProduct;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long result = productSeries();
    System.out.print(result);
}
```